# Looking for a book in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

The following are some pages of a book in real analysis. Could someone tell me who is the author?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gQQ6.jpg)
[image]

Comment: Type "This sum is the area of the rectangles in Figure IX.2" into Google and you get the answer.

Comment: Did you try to google the first line "The Riemann integral solves the problem of defining the area under the graph"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's from *Foundations of Mathematical Analysis*, by Richard Johnsonbaugh and W. E. Pfaffenberger (Dover Publications, 2010).